# Use POST variables without calling them specifically

Tags: php

All,
I have a form that has some text inputs, checkboxes, select box and a textarea. I want to submit the form with PHP using a submit button to a page for processing.

That part is fine but what I would like to do is basically get the results into an array so I can do a foreach loop to process the results.

Basically I'm trying to create a dynamic form the submits to my backend processing script and don't want to hard code in the post values like the following:

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
echo $var1;
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
echo $var2;
```

Does anyone know how to go about doing something like this or give any recommendations?

Comment: I'm not understanding. You can already `foreach` over `$_POST` via `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)`. The behavior you describe looks like `register_globals` or [`extract($_POST)`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there're no other data in your POST but these generated elements, just do

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    // do your job 
}
```

and process what you have. If you want to mix your generated entries with predefined you may want to put these generated in nested array:

```
<input ... name="generated[fieldname]" />
```

and then you iterate

```
foreach( $_POST['generated'] as $key => $val ) {
  // do your job
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use array notation:

```
<input name="vars[]" value="" />
```

Then you will have something like this as `$_POST`:

```
Array ('vars' => Array(
     0 => 'val1'
     1 => 'val2'
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the $_POST variable is an array. you just need to extract the array values by using a simple foreach loop. that's it.

I hope this example help you.

```
foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
{   
  $asig = "\$".$field_name."='".addslashes($val)."';"; 
  eval($asig); 
}
```

After running this script all the POST values will be put in a variable with the same name than the field's name.

Comment: NO. *NEVER* `eval()` code you get from a client without a gun to your head. In this case I'd just name a field like `garbage; echo "bad code here!"; //` and now everyone has the keys to your kingdom.